# Slow iterating over string using pointers

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, profiling, std

I would love to see why one of the following solution is MUCH slower than the other. Lets concider following code:

```
// create a very long string
int x,y;
bool b;
char c[10000];

for (x=0;x<10000;x++)
    c[x]='a';
string s(c);
```

now I want to iterate over string and compare each character to other. The first solution completes the task in 5 seconds:

```
for (y=0;y<100000;y++){
for (x=0;x<10000;x++){
    b = (s[x]=='a');
}}
```

and the second in 21 seconds:

```
string::iterator begin = s.begin();
string::iterator end   = s.end();
string::iterator i;

for (y=0;y<100000;y++){
    for (i=begin;i<end;i++){
        b = (*i=='a');
}}
```

Why the second is so much slower?

Comment: What are your compilation (optimization) settings? If you are not using Release (-O2 or -O3) then it means nothing at all. Actually, the second version (iterators) *should* be marginally faster.

Comment: Are you testing on an optimized build? Also, try pre-incrementing your string iterator: `++i`.

Comment: the first variation should allow for more aggressive optimization, the compiler may easily deduce that `s` is effectively constant inside the loops while in the second idiom it must ascertain that no pointer aliasing happens.

Comment: No, I'm using `-O0` optimalization flag to test things out, but after changing it to `-O0` and changing the body of loops to `b += (s[x]=='a'` (assuming b is int), with `-O3` string version is 2 times faster than the first solution - which is interesting also.

Comment: @collapsar: Funny, every benchmark out there gives a slight edge to iterators (or rather, to incremented pointers, which is what a string iterator boils down to) compared to random access.

Comment: @danilo2: So the lesson is: don't bother about performance unless you are using a release, optimized build. Debug builds have lots of safeguards so it is impossible to know what part is actual processing and what part is just debugging overhead.

Comment: @syam that's why you should never trust a human trying to second-guess and out-optimize the compiler ... ;-)

Comment: @collapsar: Haha good recovery I'll grant you that. ;) But actually when you think of it, incremented pointers need only one addition and one dereference per iteration, while random access needs two additions (index and address computation) and one dereference, which explains the difference. :)

Comment: @syam convincing analysis :).

Comment: @syam: Except that address computation is free on modern CPU's (it's done as part of the dereference, early in the pipeline)

Comment: @MSalters: good point (to be honest I stopped keeping up to date with this kind of hardware details long ago so I'll take your word, nowadays I just bother about caching issues). I guess we'll have to find another explanation than this one to explain why incremented pointers are *still* more efficient than linear indexed access... ^_^

Comment: shouldn't `x<10000` be `x<100000`?

Comment: @Elazar no it should not.

Comment: BTW c[] is not null terminated, yet you initialize the string with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is having to dereference a pointer every time you are comparing your iterator to 'a', instead of just comparing the actual char value. This is a negligible difference in most cases, but with it doing 1,000,000,000 iterations it is noticeable.